# How can I still use keyboard buttons for sound while in iPhoto?

Tags: itunes, keyboard, audio, photos.app

When I'm using iPhoto, the hard audio buttons on the keyboard (previous, pause, next) no longer apply to iTunes. Suddenly, they do things in iPhoto instead. Things like play and pause slideshows, start slideshows, work like arrow buttons, etc.

I dislike this.

Is there any way to keep the hard audio buttons being used for iTunes while I'm in iPhoto?

I'm using iPhoto 9.6.1 on Yosemite 10.10.1.

For various compatibility reasons, I'm unable to upgrade to El Capitan or the new Photos app. (I don't know if that would help me, but anyway.)

Comment: On Photos (the new one) on my mac, skip, rewind, and play/pause all control iTunes. Also note that the Photos app was introduced in Yosemite (10.10.3) so you could presumably upgrade to the new Photos app but keep Yosemite. iPhoto stays on your Mac, but it stops being the default app.

Comment: @JohnRamos Unfortuneatly I have some hardware compatibility issues, so I'm stuck with 10.10.1.

Comment: Try using this article: http://blog.viktorpetersson.com/post/92729965694/a-permanent-fix-for-apples-playpause-hijacking-and-use-s. Just pretend that iTunes is iPhoto and Spotify is iTunes.

Comment: @JohnRamos That looks promising, I'll take a look at that.